# Why does An'im Zemiros have two רs?

Tags: tefilla, song-poetry, aleph-bet-letters, shabbat-songs

The song beginning אנעים זמירות (also named Shir HaKavod), which is popularly sung in shuls on Shabbos and/or Yom Tov and/or Yamim Noraim, basically follows a letter-scheme, with one verse for each letter.

However, when it comes to the letter Reish (ר), there are two verses instead of one:

> רוֹצֶה בְּעַמּוֹ עֲנָוִים יְפָאֵר/ יוֹשֵׁב תְּהִלּוֹת בָּם לְהִתְפָּאֵר
>
> רֹאשׁ דְּבָרְךָ אֱמֶת קוֹרֵא מֵרֹאשׁ/ דּוֹר וָדוֹר עַם דּוֹרֶשְׁיךָ דְּרוֹשׁ

Why is this? Do we know if one of these two lines were always there (as the second of these two lines has a bit of an awkward rhyming scheme due to the enjambment)

Comment: The [English Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anim_Zemirot) points out that not only are there two lines with the letter Reish (ר) but also with the letter Tau (ת).

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I don't buy that.  There are 4 lines with other letters before and after the acrostic.  The first one after starts with ת.  It might be relevant and it might not.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok yeah but that's at the end so it makes more sense to me

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok It is suggested in the [Encyclopedia Judaica](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/anim-zemirot) that _the first three of the last four lines may not be part of the original poem._